# SwiftUI LazyHStack TabView inside ScrollView is hidden

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've got the following view:

```swift
#if DEBUG
struct MyTestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyTestView()
    }
}
#endif

struct MyTestView: View {
    @State var selectedTab: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                ScrollView {
                    LazyHStack {
                        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                            ForEach(0...3, id: \.self) { i in
                                Text(String(i))
                            }
                        }
                        .animation(.easeInOut)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
                    }
                }

                Spacer().frame(height: geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Test")
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        }
    }
}
```

This used to work fine pre XCode 13 & iOS 15. Now with the latest versions, my TabView items are no longer shown. At all. If I remove `ScrollView` which gives me the neccesary vertical scrolling in my real scenario, I can see my items again.

How can I have vertical scrolling in `LazyHStack -> TabView` scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day, I figured I can just move my ScrollView down:

```swift
struct MyTestView: View {
    @State var selectedTab: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                LazyHStack {
                    TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                        ForEach(0...3, id: \.self) { i in
                            ScrollView {
                                Text(String(i))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .animation(.easeInOut)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                    .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
                }

                Spacer().frame(height: geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Test")
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        }
    }
}
```

Now everything works.